# Why does Google Translate omit such a large part of this text?

Tags: google-translate

I've encountered the following post on Stack Overflow en español:

> Tengo un problema no se si parecido, no me muesteas las imagenes, mi priblema es con las imagenes dentro de la carpeta media, se suben al servidor pero no se muestran, soy nuevo ne django y esto jejeje te puede vol er loco, me podrian ayudar?

When I try to [translate it into English](https://translate.google.nl/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=Tengo%20un%20problema%20no%20se%20si%20parecido%2C%20no%20me%20muesteas%20las%20imagenes%2C%20mi%20priblema%20es%20con%20las%20imagenes%20dentro%20de%20la%20carpeta%20media%2C%20se%20suben%20al%20servidor%20pero%20no%20se%20muestran%2C%20soy%20nuevo%20ne%20django%20y%20esto%20jejeje%20te%20puede%20vol%20er%20loco%2C%20me%20podrian%20ayudar%3F&op=translate) with Google Translate, all I get is

> I have a problem. help?

[image]

which is a translation of just the first three words and the last word of the text I entered.

What would cause this problem (perhaps that's off-topic for Web Applications, but the following is not IMHO), and **as a Google Translate end user, what can I do to prevent these kind of things**? I can see there are some typos in the source text ('muesteas' should be 'muestras'; 'priblema' should be 'problema'; 'nuevo ne django' should be 'nuevo en Django'). Fixing those typos [seems to solve the problem](https://translate.google.nl/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=Tengo%20un%20problema%20no%20se%20si%20parecido%2C%20no%20me%20muestras%20las%20imagenes%2C%20mi%20problema%20es%20con%20las%20imagenes%20dentro%20de%20la%20carpeta%20media%2C%20se%20suben%20al%20servidor%20pero%20no%20se%20muestran%2C%20soy%20nuevo%20en%20django%20y%20esto%20jejeje%20te%20puede%20vol%20er%20loco%2C%20me%20podrian%20ayudar%3F&op=translate) but one can't expect this from less proficient speakers. I would expect Google Translate to make more mistakes than usual, but not completely omit sentence parts (let alone complete sentences...).

I did some analysis and something similar happens when I translate it into Dutch or German. However, [translating to French](https://translate.google.nl/?sl=auto&tl=fr&text=Tengo%20un%20problema%20no%20se%20si%20parecido%2C%20no%20me%20muesteas%20las%20imagenes%2C%20mi%20priblema%20es%20con%20las%20imagenes%20dentro%20de%20la%20carpeta%20media%2C%20se%20suben%20al%20servidor%20pero%20no%20se%20muestran%2C%20soy%20nuevo%20ne%20django%20y%20esto%20jejeje%20te%20puede%20vol%20er%20loco%2C%20me%20podrian%20ayudar%3F&op=translate) seems to work fine:

> J'ai un problème je ne sais pas si c'est similaire, vous ne me montrez pas les images, mon problème est avec les images à l'intérieur du dossier multimédia, elles sont téléchargées sur le serveur mais elles ne s'affichent pas, je suis nouveau sur django et cela peut vous rendre fou, ils pourraient moi aider?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Did you used the autodetec option? Did you tried this in incognito with and without being signed in your Google account? Are you using a free account or a G Suite / Google Workspace account?

Comment: Try using `sl=es&tl=en` as URL query parameters. They were added automatically when I tried to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Rubén they're added for me too. It doesn't matter whether I use autodetect or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think that only Google can answer this. I suggest you to submit your feedback direclty to Google. Click the Send feedback link at the bottom of the right box

[image]

Also you can click on the Menu (three lines button, on the top left corner, then Send feedback)

Also you can help Google Translate to be better by participating as a contributor. To do that click the Contribute button below the boxes.

Comment: I noticed that feedback option earlier today and shared a link to this question as well. I hope somebody from Google provides a deep insight into this :)

Comment: There used to be a time when a Google regularly come here to answer questions but, in my experience, they very rarely "provides" (I mean publicly share) their deep insights but they review all the feedback received.